# Fetch 10000 coordinates synchronously using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, synchronous

I want to fetch coordinates of 10,000 line of data using Google Maps geocoding API, and print each line to browser. 
My approach is to loop each line (contain address) and pass it to Google Maps URL, then I parse those JSON data to get its lat and lng. I use jQuery.
But the problem here is it seems to run asynchronously. I have tried to use recursive but it loop without print anything. I have read to set async=false but I dont know where to place it.
Here is my current code

```
var x = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        geturl = 'parse.php?urut='+x;
        $.get(geturl, function(get){
            url = get;
        });
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lang = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            var nama = data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
            $('table').append("<tr><td>"+x+"</td><td>"+lat+","+lang+"</td><td>"+nama+"</td></tr>");
        });
        x++;
    }, 500);
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: you want to run the fetches one after the other, correct?

Comment: async=false is deprecated. To get this to work you have to call the resulting parsing of the data after receiving it. See for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, exactly.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thank you, I'm going to figure it out

Comment: @AbidFamasya - did you want to fetch all 10000 in parallel, or only one at a time?

Comment: Are you aware of the [geocoding API usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code should show you where you went wrong

```
function getCoords(x) {
    geturl = 'parse.php?urut='+x;
    $.get(geturl, function(url){
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lang = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            var nama = data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
            $('table').append("<tr><td>"+x+"</td><td>"+lat+","+lang+"</td><td>"+nama+"</td></tr>");
        });
   });
}
```

the $.getJSON is run as part of the success function of the $.get - therefore it will get run only once the $.get is complete

I've shown this as a function, so that the value of `x` will be correct in the `$('table').append` line

Comment: cool! there's issue where the printed result skip few "x". But I think I can solve it. thank you in advance.

Comment: the output order is dependant on the response order of the final getJSON - so, if you start 10000 of these, don't expect them to be in the same order that you started them, unless you wait for each response before sending the next request